# Assigning a missing device by udev

Tags: linux, debian, pci, udev

Given that I have a PCI parallel port that [isn't recognized](https://superuser.com/questions/1678489/parallel-port-mini-pci-express-adapter-not-assigned-in-linux) in some way, I was considering if writing a **udev** rule for it could make my day.
I found some [old note](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) discouraging from doing it:

> Writing rules is not a workaround for the problem where no device nodes for your particular device exist. Even if there are no matching rules, udev will create the device node with the default name supplied by the kernel.

However, in my case udev is not creating the device.
If I increase udev log level in `/etc/udev/udev.conf` with

```
udev_log=debug
```

all I get is a very detailed log from udev; there are some tries(?) to assign device `parport0` but I really can't decipher why they fail (or are deleted).

In my insane plan, what line(s) could I add to my `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-general.rules` file to test and try add my PCIe parallel port?

Comment: You could include the log, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

udev hasn't been creating device nodes for about a decade. It still loads kernel modules and manages /dev file permissions and symlinks, but the actual device nodes (chardevs, blockdevs) are managed by *devtmpfs* – they  will automagically pop up on their own as soon as a driver calls device_register(). If nothing shows up in /dev, then no driver has registered a "parport" device.

This means that creating device nodes manually would be a bit useless; there's no device number that you could pass to mknod that would correspond to a device that doesn't exist.

(devtmpfs was added in 2009 around kernel release 2.6.32. It is not to be confused with devfs, which was a much more complex facility that was removed in 2006.)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, then I can't do much else than changing/recompiling the kernel, as the stock one coming in Debian 11 doesn't recognize anymore my PCIe parallel port... Quite odd, as with Debian 10 and 9 it worked like a charm :shrug: